# My Python Bokeh plot not displaying in browser: "raise ProtocolError("Token is expired.")

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am reaching out regarding a Python agent-based example code I have been working on to simulate an evacuation during a disaster. For the most part, my logic seems to be functioning as intended. However, I am encountering an issue with my interactive simulation plot, which is not behaving as expected.

I am relatively new to the `bokeh` library in Python. My intention is to display the interactive plot in the browser, but unfortunately, it continues to time out after nearly an hour.

I have included my complete code below for your reference.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance you could provide.

Thank you in advance.

```
from mesa import Agent, Model
from mesa.time import RandomActivation
from mesa.space import MultiGrid
from mesa.datacollection import DataCollector
import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
# from bokeh.io import push_notebook
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.server.server import Server


class Person(Agent):
    """
    A class representing a person in the evacuation model.
    """

    def __init__(self, unique_id, model):
        """
        Initialize a person agent.

        Args:
            unique_id (int): Unique identifier for the agent.
            model: Reference to the model containing the agent.
        """
        super().__init__(unique_id, model)
        self.evacuated = False

    def move(self):
        """
        Move the person agent to a random neighboring cell if within grid boundaries and not evacuated.
        """
        if not self.evacuated:
            possible_moves = self.model.grid.get_neighborhood(
                self.pos,
                moore=True,
                include_center=False
            )
            new_position = random.choice(possible_moves)
            if self.model.grid.is_cell_empty(new_position):
                self.model.grid.move_agent(self, new_position)

    def step(self):
        """
        Method called in each step of the model's execution.
        """
        if not self.evacuated:
            self.move()
            x, y = self.pos
            if x < 0 or x >= self.model.grid.width or y < 0 or y >= self.model.grid.height:
                self.evacuated = True


class EvacuationModel(Model):
    """
    A class representing the evacuation model.
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, num_agents):
        """
        Initialize the evacuation model.

        Args:
            width (int): Width of the grid.
            height (int): Height of the grid.
            num_agents (int): Number of person agents in the model.
        """
        self.num_agents = num_agents
        self.grid = MultiGrid(width, height, True)
        self.schedule = RandomActivation(self)

        # Create agents
        for i in range(self.num_agents):
            agent = Person(i, self)
            x = random.randrange(self.grid.width)
            y = random.randrange(self.grid.height)
            self.grid.place_agent(agent, (x, y))
            self.schedule.add(agent)

        # Bokeh setup
        self.source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': [], 'y': [], 'evacuated': []})
        self.plot = figure(width=800, height=800, title='Agent Evacuation Process',
                           x_range=[0, self.grid.width], y_range=[0, self.grid.height])
        self.plot.square(x='x', y='y', source=self.source, size=20, color='blue')

        self.datacollector = DataCollector(
            agent_reporters={"Evacuated": "evacuated"}
        )

    def step(self):
        """
        Method called in each step of the model's execution.
        Collects data and advances the model by one step.
        """
        self.datacollector.collect(self)
        self.schedule.step()

        # Update Bokeh data
        agent_data = [{'x': agent.pos[0], 'y': agent.pos[1], 'evacuated': agent.evacuated} for agent in
                      self.schedule.agents]
        self.source.data = {'x': [data['x'] for data in agent_data],
                            'y': [data['y'] for data in agent_data],
                            'evacuated': [data['evacuated'] for data in agent_data]}
        push_notebook()


# Set up the server
def modify_doc(doc):
    width = 10
    height = 10
    num_agents = 50

    evacuation_model = EvacuationModel(width, height, num_agents)

    # Run the simulation for 10 steps with interactive plotting
    output_notebook()
    show(evacuation_model.plot, notebook_handle=True)

    for i in range(10):
        evacuation_model.step()


# To access the visualization, run this server code in your Python environment
server = Server({'/': modify_doc}, num_procs=1)
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening Bokeh application on http://localhost:5006/')
    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. `output_notebook`,`show` and `push_notebook` are generally never applicable to Bokeh server applications. More importantly, your `modify_doc` function does not actually modify the document. Typically it would call `doc.add_root` to add some Bokeh objects to display. It's not really clear how you are expecting to use this, or have it work for users, and that matters in terms of what advice or docs to point you at.

Comment: @bigreddot \ Thanks for your comments. However, could you clarify a little bit on your first comment regarding `output_notebook`, `show`, and `push_notebook`? I have seen others use these with the bokeh library. Are you implying that these are not native to bokeh? The usage in my code is not correct?

Comment: No, that is not what I said. They are a part of Bokeh, but they are not used for *Bokeh server applications* which is what you appear to be trying to create, since you are using `Server` and `modify_doc`. Those functions are typically only used for standalone Bokeh output (i.e. static HTML+JS output with no server).

Comment: Clarifying: "those functions" above refers to `output_notebook`, `show`, and `push_notebook`.

Comment: @bigreddot \ I appreciate the clarifications.